# How to select all output of a cell in jupyter notebook on mac to copy output?

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, clipboard, macbookpro

If I try `command+A` while the pointer is in the cell output, this selects the whole notebook. Is there a way to select just the output of the cell? Or a way to get it into clipboard? On macOS Ventura 13.5.1, using python 3.10.11, jupyter notebook version 6.5.4, and a very long ouptut. I'm trying to copy outside of jupyter notebook.

Comment: right-click -> copy output to clipboard

Comment: Are you on a mac? I don't see that option.

Comment: Yes, Mac in JupyterLab

Comment: I'm using jupyter notebook

Comment: Ah, OK. You can always open your .ipynb files in Jupyter Lab but I am not sure if that right click option is available in notebook.

Answer (score 0):

on jupyter notebook, go to the cell, hit escape, hit c - it will copy to your clipboard, if you want to paste it to another cell hit escape, hit v it will paste it to a new cell

Comment: This copied the cell from one to the next, but I couldn't copy outside of jupyter notebook. I don't think it went to the computers clipboard

Comment: i wander why cmd+a+c, and cmd+v not working

Comment: As soon as I type cmd+a it selects the whole notebook. Maybe a setting was changed somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click and do 'show as JSON'.
   [image: json]
2. Then do Ctrl + A & copy from python file.
   [image: copy]

Comment: Right click where? I don't see this option.

Comment: right click to output of given cell.

Comment: I don't see that. Are you on mac?

Comment: Not on mac but I guess this should not be os specific.

Comment: macs are different. ctrl + A doesn't select all, for one thing.